# Combine Python lists with similar elements

Tags: python, list

I'd like to merge to lists with many similar elements preserving the order as much as possible.

So say for example we have this:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
list2=[1,2,3,4,5,8,10]

list1+list2=[1,2,3,4,6,5,7,8,9,10]
```

or maybe:

```
list1+list2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,9]
```

The idea is that 1,2,3,4 all match.  Then we encounter 5 in list1 and 6 in list2 and we insert them next to each other in the merge list.  If there are more elements in one list than the other then the extra rows are just appended to the end.

Comment: `sorted(set(list1 + list2))`?

Comment: Only as another way in writing the code that is written by @Samwise:  
`sorted(set(list1) | set(list2))`

Answer (score 0):

- For unsorted output-
  `list(set(list1+list2))`
- For sorted output-
  `list(sorted(set(list1+list2)))`